# JSP c:forEach items attribute cannot resolve variable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I using `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1` lib in my JSP project.

Here's my code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
// other classes are included too
<%
Tools tools = new Tools();
news [] list = tools.getEvent();
%>

<html>
<body>

<c:forEach var="i" items="${list}"> <-- cannot resolve variable 'list', why?
/* Do something */
</c:forEach>

</body
</html>
```

As you see, the 'list' variable extsts but invisible for forEach. What i missed? c:out works fine.
It crashes with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp` signature.

Strange things are happens...
I tried to execute this:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
    <c:out value="works"/>
</c:forEach>
```

But i got the same error..

Comment: Why are you mixing up scriplets and JSTL? You can't use a variable defined in scriplets, in an EL expression. Rather, add the object as request attribute.

Comment: @Rohit thanks, please read the topic's update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a servlet 2.3 container or higher (and I'm sure you are), then JSTL 1.2 (possibly higher) should be inherently available to your JSP pages.  You shouldn't need to add a JSTL JAR to your deployment.  In fact, Tomcat's default configuration will *explicitly ignore* any classes in your deployment JAR's that start with javax.servlet.*, and use its own versions instead.

To be available to expression language (EL), the value needs to be an attribute of either the page context, request object, session object, or servlet context.

To expose your value as a page context attribute:

```
<%
Tools tools = new Tools();
news [] list = tools.getEvent();
pageContext.setAttribute("list", list);
%>
```